# node-soap trouble with array

Tags: node.js, soap

I have a webservice I'm trying to call using node soap. I'm getting an extra elment  in the generated XML when I need to make a call with an array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns5="http://com.tch.cards.service/types/arrays/com/tch/cards/model" xmlns:tns="http://com.tch.cards.service" xmlns:ns2="http://com.tch.cards.service/types" xmlns:ns4="http://com.tch.cards.service/types/arrays/" xmlns:ns3="http://com.tch.cards.service/types/arrays/java/lang">
        <soap:Body>
            <tns:getTransLocations>
                <clientId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</clientId>
                <locationIds>
                    <tns:locationIds>
                        <value>599996</value>
                        <value>599998</value>
                    </tns:locationIds>
                </locationIds>
            </tns:getTransLocations>
        </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem above is the `</tns:locationIds>` element. What I need is the XML to look like this

```
<locationIds>
                    <value>599996</value>
                    <value>599998</value>
 </locationIds>
```

Here's the js code I'm using to generate the call

```
let client = await soap.createClientAsync(url,{namespaceArrayElements:false});
 var id = [{value:'599996'}, {value:'599998'}];

        let args = {
            clientId:this.token,
            'locationIds':id,
        }

        let result = await this.client.getTransLocationsAsync(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually test this, but I'd try something like

```
let client = await soap.createClientAsync(url,{namespaceArrayElements:false});
let args = {
    clientId:this.token,
    locationIds: {
        value: [599996, 599998]
    }
}

let result = await client.getTransLocationsAsync(args);
```

Comment: That was closer but still not what I needed, it concatenated items in the array together in the values element like <tns.value>599996599998 </tns.value> It also left the prefix on the value element and the web service didn't like that. I ended up switching to strong-soap and all was good.